# Set As Default Home Page With JavaScript - FireFox & IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, default

what are the best codes for setting a web address as default home page on client?

mean on (pageload)

for ie8 and firefox 3(or more)

thanks 4 future attention

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, it's up to the user.

Comment: thanks 4 answer / i know it's up to user / but is there any code about that for body onload / i test some code => 4 working we should really click on something and it seems those codes only work on IE!

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. Browsers do not allow a web page to change your home site. Period.